# What is the relation between the column space of two matrix.

Tags: vector-spaces

What is the relation between the column space of matrix $X$ and the column space of $X^TX$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column space of $(X^TX)$ is subspace of row space of $X$. There is no relation between column space of $X^TX$ and $X$ as such. They might not be in same space as well if $X\in R^{m\times n}$ and $m \ne n$.

Answer (score 0):

The column space of $X$ and $X^TX$ have the same dimension (at least for real valued matrices).

This follows since one can show that they have equal kernel (and hence row space).

It is trivial that $N(X) \subseteq N(X^TX)$ where $N(X)$ is the null space of $X$. Suppose that $v\in N(X^TX)$, so that $X^TXv=0$ and $v^TX^TXv=0$. This then implies that $Xv=0$ since $v^TX^TXv = ||Xv||^2_2$ and so we have the reverse inclusion $N(X^TX)\subseteq N(X)$. Therefore, we have that $N(X)=N(X^TX)$ and by rank nullity we have that the row spaces are equal and the column spaces have equal dimension.